# R Custom proxy function in dtw for wraping

Tags: r, wrapper

I have two column of data Tm and Ts and I want to apply the dtw algorithm changing the distance function. Proxy provide this possibility but I can't understand why it gives me an error. 
I have 2 vector of data with the same length:

```
 Tm     Ts  
 301.0607   300.6008
 301.3406   300.6515     
 301.5912   300.7289    
 301.5777   300.8506    
 301.5996   301.0158    
 301.6414   301.2103    
 301.7181   301.4113    


 myDTW<-function(x,y)(diff(x,lag=1,difference=1)-diff(y,lag=1,difference=1))^2
 pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = myDTW, names = c("test_myDTW", "myDTW"))

 Alignment<-dtw(a$Ts,b$Tm,dist.method="test_myDTW",keep.internals=TRUE)

 Error in do.call(".External", c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, 
 if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method),  : 
 not a scalar return value
```

diff() changes the length of the vector from n to n-1 but both vectors are changed, so I think that the problem are not on matching vector of different length.
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is explicit :

```
   not a scalar return value
```

Your myDTW don't return a scalar. You need to define it as a valid distance function. If you change it to something like :

```
myDTW <- function(x,y){
        res <- (diff(x,lag=1,difference=1)
                       -diff(y,lag=1,difference=1))^2
        sum(res) ## I return the sum of square here
      }
```

It will works. I think also you need to use `modify_entry` to modify the method value in the register.

```
dat <- read.table(text='Tm     Ts  
301.0607   300.6008
301.3406   300.6515     
301.5912   300.7289    
301.5777   300.8506    
301.5996   301.0158    
301.6414   301.2103    
301.7181   301.4113',header=TRUE)    


myDTW <- function(x,y){
        res <- (diff(x,lag=1,difference=1)
                       -diff(y,lag=1,difference=1))^2
        sum(res)
                           }
pr_DB$modify_entry(FUN = myDTW, names = c("test_myDTW", "myDTW"))
library(dtw)
## I change a and b to dat here
dtw(dat$Ts,dat$Tm,dist.method="test_myDTW",keep.internals=TRUE)
```

The result is :

```
DTW alignment object
 Alignment size (query x reference): 7 x 7
 Call: dtw(x = dat$Ts, y = dat$Tm, dist.method = "test_myDTW", keep.internals = TRUE)
```

Comment: Many thanks. So the error was not considering the Sum of differences inside the function.

Comment: No the error was not returning a scalar , you returned a vector. I used `sum` , you can use `max` for example , or  any custom function returning a scalar.